# Trying to sort out msi installer security permission requirements

Tags: windows, installation, components, conditional-statements, launch

I've been asked to sort out what the security requirements are for our MSI installers.  Unfortunately, I'm a bit stuck on what is required of a Windows Installer Component ID Launch Condition.  I can't seem to dig up where those component id's are even stored.  Any insight would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: What's a "Windows Installer Component ID Launch Condition"? I'm not familiar with this term. Can you give me more details?

Comment: You mean you are trying to work out where in the registry the component IDs are stored so that you can decide whether your app can access them when it uses an AppSearch action to determine whether a component is installed and then set a property used in a LaunchCondition?

Comment: @CosminPirvu - When you setup your Launch Conditions of a Visual Studio Setup Project, you can create 3 types of launch conditions, Registry Search, File Search, or Windows Installer Search.  The Windows Installer Search uses Component ID's.

Comment: @StephenConnolly - Basically.  Though what i've been reading, Windows Installer maintains a database as opposed to storing install information in the Registry.  I don't know where that database resides, but if it's true then I need to find it and figure out what permissions are required by the user during an installation...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: there are no permissions required. Everyone can evaluate the launch condition.

Components are handled internally by Windows Installer, along with the cached MSI. It doesn't matter where their information is stored because Windows Installer is fully integrated with user accounts, permissions and the UAC.

Basically, Windows Installer can do whatever it wants. None of its built-in actions will fail because of permissions because they were designed this way.

Additonally, searches only read information. Since the component information is stored internally and it's not accessible to your users, there's no reason a permission problem would occur.

Comment: I can't really mark this as answered or vote it up as I really don't have the bandwidth right now to test this out and confirm it's accuracy.  Just the same, I really appriciate the feed back!  Thank you!  Hopefully people more knowledgable than I can vote this up.